# How to return the header of react navigation to the default value

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using `drawer` in `react-navigation`. I am making the drawer header change depending on the situation. I added a serach button to the right of the drawer header, and when this button is pressed, `headerLeft` and `headerTitle` are changed. The picture below is defaultHeader.

[image: Default Header]

Header changes as shown below when right button is pressed.
[image: SearchBar Header]

I want to change it back to the original header value when I left click on the searchBar Header. However, in the function I wrote, it does not return to the original header value even when the left button is pressed. I changed the header in `Drawer Navigator` using `navigation props` passed through Screen. As in the **second code**, how to revert to the original state when the header is changed through `setOptions`?

```
<Drawer.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Inbox"
    screenOptions={{
        drawerType: "front",
        headerRightContainerStyle: {
            right: 16,
        },
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#4E7589",
            shadowOpacity: 0.1,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 30,
            borderBottomRightRadius: 30,
            shadowColor: "black",
        },
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "white" },
        overlayColor: "transparent",
        drawerLabelStyle: {
            fontFamily: "nanumSquareB",
            fontSize: 16,
        },
        drawerActiveBackgroundColor: "transparent",
        drawerActiveTintColor: "#FF6148",
        drawerInactiveTintColor: "#000",
        drawerInactiveBackgroundColor: "white",
        drawerItemStyle: {
            borderRadius: 0,
            width: "100%",
            marginLeft: -8,
            paddingLeft: 0,
        },
    }}
    drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
>
    <Drawer.Screen name="drawer" component={InboxScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

```
const InboxScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (searchMode) {
            navigation.setOptions({
                headerLeft: () => (
                    <FontAwesome style={{ left: 16 }} onPress={() => setSearchMode(false)} name="close" size={20} />
                ),
                headerTitle: () => (
                    <TextInput value={inputText} onChangeText={setInputText} placeholder="PlaceHolder" />
                ),
                headerRight: () => <FontAwesome onPress={() => setSearchWord(inputText)} name="search" size={20} />,
            });
        } else {
            navigation.setOptions({
                headerRight: () => <FontAwesome onPress={() => setSearchMode(true)} name="search" size={20} />,
            });
        }
    }, [searchMode]);
}
```